# Angular2 getElementsByClassName on ElementRef

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following constructor in my component :

```
constructor (private el: ElementRef) {this.el = el.nativeElement}
```

then in my `ngOnInit` :

```
ngOnInit() {
 let foos = this.el.getElementsByClassName('foo')
}
```

triggers : `TS2339: Property 'getElementsByClassName' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.`

I did try converting my `ElementRef` to an `HTMLElement` by without any success. Any idea how to deal with that error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `private`:

```
el:HtmlElement;
constructor (el: ElementRef) {this.el = el.nativeElement}
```

With your original code `this.el` will be declared as type `ElementRef` but then an `HTMLElement` will be assigned. This is why you get the error message.